# Excel VBA Check value of cell (first 3 characters) against a list on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Lets say cell "A1" needs to be check after data has been entered, (I have the stuff that will go to a sub module already so that's not an issue)

Now I need to verify that the data entered is using a prefix from sheet2 with a range of C2:C250, most use 3 character, but some are 4, so I need to make sure that the first 3-4 characters of the data match that range. and then I also need to make sure that after the first 3 or 4 characters match that they do not put a space.

```
Valid prefix examples
ABC
SEDC
SDR
SCT
KJLS
LOS

Example of cell value
ABC12XZY34 - Would match on ABC and no space = Valid
SEDC12XZY34 - Would also match on SEDC and no spcae = Valid
ABC 12ZYX12 - Would match on ABC but there is a space = Invalid
SEDC 12XYZ34 - Would match on SEDC but there is a spcae = Invalid
ABC12 XZY34 - Would match on ABC and no space right after prefix = Valid
SEDC12 XZY34 - Would also match on SEDC and no space right after prefix = Valid
```

I am unsure how to make a match on just first 3 or 4 char and then make sure there is no space right after the prefix but there can be spaces elsewhere.

Prefix could be any combo of 3-4 chr, and rest could be and combo of chr including spaces, just not after the prefix.

We have some users who keep putting a space after the prefix and it causes errors on the back end and need to force them to fix it.

Need it to run in a VBA Sub.

Thanks for helping.

Updated: Added more clear detail on needs.

Comment: why the -1? would be nice if you would let me know so I can do better next time.

Comment: The downvote is most likely because your question shows no evidence of any effort to solve the problem. Suggest you familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Will the character after the prefix always be a digit?

Comment: Ron, No I have updated my OP to help clarify. I missed adding in some info. Any I did not post any code as I had noting even close to working or even correct. Things I tried did not work, was not sure I even had the correct functions in my code. but next time I will post it. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this if you wanted a VBA solution:

```
Sub check_prefix()
    'Get text from the cell that you want to check.
    'I'm suposing that the cell is active because you said that you want to execute the code when the user
    'change a value
    If InStr(ActiveCell.Text, " ") Or Len(ActiveCell.Text) < 3 Then
        'The value is invalid.Do something
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'check if there is any compatible prefix the parameter

    If Len(ActiveCell.Text) < 4 Then
        Set Cells4 = Nothing
    Else
        Set Cells4 = Worksheets("Prefix").Range("C1:C250").Find(What:=Left(ActiveCell.Text, 4), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    End If
    Set Cells3 = Worksheets("Prefix").Range("C1:C250").Find(What:=Left(ActiveCell.Text, 3), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Cells3 Is Nothing And Cells4 Is Nothing Then
        'The value is invalid.Do something
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'The value is valid.Do something

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked great, had to modify it just a bit for my use. ActiveCell was not working due to the way my sheet and other VBA is setup, Had to use Range("I" & x).Text (its always the "I column" and x = active row, otherwise it worked just the way you had it (Adjusted the range to my needs). Thanks so much I was nowhere even close to this code.

Comment: Sorry spoke to soon, It checks for any spaces, I need it to only check if there is a space in the 4 or 5 spot (Right after the prefixes) the rest of the result could have spaces. Example: "ABC12 ab12321" would be ok. - - -  "ABC 12 AB12321" would not Sorry I was not more clear.

Comment: You may use InStr(left(ActiveCell.Text,5), " ") to check the first five characters or InStr(mid(ActiveCell.Text,4,2), " ") to check only the 4th and 5th characters

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula, where the number to be checked is in A1.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, $A1 &"0123456789"))-1),Sheet2!$C$2:$C$250,0)),"Invalid","Valid")
```

And here is the entire development sequence, in case you need to fine tune it.

```
[A1 =] ABC 1234

[C1] =MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, $A1 &"0123456789"))

[D1] =LEFT($A1,$C1-1)

[E1] =MATCH($D1,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$250,0)  -  returns #N/A in this case

[F1] =IF(ISNA(MATCH($D1,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$250,0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Replace $D1 in the formula in F1 with the formula in D1.

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT($A1,$C1-1),Sheet2!$C$2:$C$250,0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Replace C1 in the above formula with the formula in C1

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(LEFT($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, $A1 &"0123456789"))-1),Sheet2!$C$2:$C$250,0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

True = "Invalid" (because ISNA asks if there is an error which there is , in this case) and Fals = "Valid"

Comment: needed a VBA SUB version, and there could be alphanumeric after the prifex including spaces, just no space right after the prefix. Updated OP to clarify. But thanks for the effort. (I think you missed my "need to run in a sub" I clarified it to say "VBA Sub"